# How to FIll GAP in SQL Server with Previous Value based upon UserAccount ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have table with 2 account id who has different start month and year  as with below data

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    AccountId NVARCHAR(100),
    Churn NVARCHAR(100), 
    [Month] INT, 
    [Yr] INT
)

INSERT INTO #Temp 
VALUES ('Tst05716825', 'Active', 9, 2016), ('Tst05716825', 'Active', 12, 2016),
       ('Tst05716825', 'Suspend', 3, 2017), ('Tst05716825', 'Suspend', 8, 2017),
       ('Tst05716825', 'Terminate', 10, 2017), ('TstNew09567', 'Active', 11, 2017),
       ('TstNew09567', 'Suspend', 2, 2018), ('TstNew09567', 'Suspend', 4, 2018),
       ('TstNew09567', 'Terminate', 6, 2018),
         ('TstNw09567', 'Active', 3, 2016),
     ('TstNw09567', 'Terminate', 3, 2018);

SELECT * 
FROM #Temp
```

Output as below

```
AccountId   Churn     Month   Yr
-----------------------------------
Tst05716825 Active     9    2016
Tst05716825 Active    12    2016
Tst05716825 Suspend    3    2017
Tst05716825 Suspend    8    2017
Tst05716825 Terminate   10  2017
TstNew09567 Active      11  2017
TstNew09567 Suspend     2   2018
TstNew09567 Suspend     4   2018
TstNew09567 Terminate   6   2018
TstNw09567  Active      3   2016
TstNw09567  Terminate   3   2018
```

But I need to fill in missing year and month by previous value for each user start month and year will select first month value from table. Need output as below:

```
AccountId   Churn   Month    Yr
Tst05716825 Active    9      2016
Tst05716825 Active    10     2016
Tst05716825 Active    11     2016
Tst05716825 Active    12     2016
Tst05716825 Active    1      2017
Tst05716825 Active    2      2017
Tst05716825 Suspend   3      2017
Tst05716825 Suspend   4      2017
Tst05716825 Suspend   5      2017
Tst05716825 Suspend   6      2017
Tst05716825 Suspend   7      2017
Tst05716825 Suspend   8      2017
Tst05716825 Suspend   9      2017
Tst05716825 Terminate 10     2017
TstNew09567 Active    11     2017
TstNew09567 Active    12     2017
TstNew09567 Active    1      2018
TstNew09567 Suspend   2      2018
TstNew09567 Suspend   3      2018
TstNew09567 Suspend   4      2018
TstNew09567 Suspend   5      2018
TstNew09567 Terminate 6      2018
TstNw09567  Active    3      2016
TstNw09567  Active    4      2016 till Feb 2018 as Active
TstNw09567  Terminate  3     2018
```

I need help to fix this in query. I dont want to use while loop because we have data size very huge.

Comment: Yes OP, I understood your requirement that you want to generate dates `AccountId` to maintain gap. But `it's quite different than initial requirement` and not sure again if it will be your final requirement ?

Comment: Thanks for your response. this was my final requirement as I mentioned start of this thread in subject fill "GAP by AccountId".

Comment: Yes, its clear after adding more data, before it was not clear like this while checking expected data only and unfortunately I missed the text `GAP by AccountId`. Please check the updated answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically creating a calendar cte with `AccountId` included. So you get all missing months and year for each account (also from min to max date for that account).

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#calendar') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #calendar;

CREATE TABLE #Temp
    (
        AccountId NVARCHAR(100) ,
        Churn NVARCHAR(100) ,
        [Month] INT ,
        [Yr] INT
    );

INSERT INTO #Temp
VALUES ( 'Tst05716825', 'Active', 9, 2016 ) ,
       ( 'Tst05716825', 'Active', 12, 2016 ) ,
       ( 'Tst05716825', 'Suspend', 3, 2017 ) ,
       ( 'Tst05716825', 'Suspend', 8, 2017 ) ,
       ( 'Tst05716825', 'Terminate', 10, 2017 ) ,
       ( 'TstNew09567', 'Active', 11, 2017 ) ,
       ( 'TstNew09567', 'Suspend', 2, 2018 ) ,
       ( 'TstNew09567', 'Suspend', 4, 2018 ) ,
       ( 'TstNew09567', 'Terminate', 6, 2018 ) ,
       ( 'TstNw09567', 'Active', 3, 2016 ) ,
       ( 'TstNw09567', 'Terminate', 3, 2018 );



DECLARE @FromDate DATETIME ,
        @ToDate DATETIME;

SELECT @FromDate = MIN(CAST(CONCAT(Yr, '-', Month, '-', 01) AS DATE)) ,
       @ToDate = MAX(CAST(CONCAT(Yr, '-', Month, '-', 01) AS DATE))
FROM   #Temp;

DECLARE @MinDt DATE ,
        @MaxDt DATE;

SELECT   TOP ( DATEDIFF(MONTH, @FromDate, @ToDate) + 1 ) calendarDate = CAST(DATEADD(
                                                                                 MONTH ,
                                                                                 number ,
                                                                                 @FromDate) AS DATE) ,
                                                         Month = MONTH(
                                                                     DATEADD(
                                                                         MONTH ,
                                                                         number ,
                                                                         @FromDate)) ,
                                                         Year = YEAR(
                                                                    DATEADD(
                                                                        MONTH ,
                                                                        number ,
                                                                        @FromDate))
INTO     #calendar
FROM     [master].dbo.spt_values
WHERE    [type] = N'P'
ORDER BY number;

;WITH AccountCal
AS ( SELECT  DISTINCT t.AccountId ,
                      cal.calendarDate
     FROM    (   SELECT   MAX(calendarDate) AS calendarDate
                 FROM     #calendar c
                 GROUP BY c.Year ,
                          c.Month ) cal
             CROSS JOIN (   SELECT AccountId ,
                                   MIN(DATEFROMPARTS(Yr, Month, 1)) OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId ) AS Mindate ,
                                   MAX(DATEFROMPARTS(Yr, Month, 1)) OVER ( PARTITION BY AccountId ) AS Maxdate 
                            FROM   #Temp ) t
     WHERE   cal.calendarDate
     BETWEEN t.Mindate AND t.Maxdate )


SELECT   cal.AccountId ,
         x.Churn ,
         MONTH(cal.calendarDate) AS Month ,
         YEAR(cal.calendarDate) AS Yr
FROM     AccountCal cal
         CROSS APPLY (   SELECT   TOP 1 Churn
                         FROM     #Temp t
                         WHERE    t.AccountId = cal.AccountId
                                  AND DATEFROMPARTS(t.Yr, t.Month, 1) <= cal.calendarDate
                         ORDER BY DATEFROMPARTS(t.Yr, t.Month, 1) DESC ) AS x
ORDER BY cal.AccountId ,
         cal.calendarDate;
```

Result:

```
+-------------+-----------+-------+------+
|  AccountId  |   Churn   | Month |  Yr  |
+-------------+-----------+-------+------+
| Tst05716825 | Active    |     9 | 2016 |
| Tst05716825 | Active    |    10 | 2016 |
| Tst05716825 | Active    |    11 | 2016 |
| Tst05716825 | Active    |    12 | 2016 |
| Tst05716825 | Active    |     1 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Active    |     2 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Suspend   |     3 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Suspend   |     4 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Suspend   |     5 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Suspend   |     6 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Suspend   |     7 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Suspend   |     8 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Suspend   |     9 | 2017 |
| Tst05716825 | Terminate |    10 | 2017 |
| TstNew09567 | Active    |    11 | 2017 |
| TstNew09567 | Active    |    12 | 2017 |
| TstNew09567 | Active    |     1 | 2018 |
| TstNew09567 | Suspend   |     2 | 2018 |
| TstNew09567 | Suspend   |     3 | 2018 |
| TstNew09567 | Suspend   |     4 | 2018 |
| TstNew09567 | Suspend   |     5 | 2018 |
| TstNew09567 | Terminate |     6 | 2018 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     3 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     4 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     5 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     6 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     7 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     8 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     9 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |    10 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |    11 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |    12 | 2016 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     1 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     2 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     3 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     4 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     5 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     6 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     7 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     8 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     9 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |    10 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |    11 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |    12 | 2017 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     1 | 2018 |
| TstNw09567  | Active    |     2 | 2018 |
| TstNw09567  | Terminate |     3 | 2018 |
+-------------+-----------+-------+------+
```

Comment: This logic is getting fail if we have another user in same Year and Month. It shows only one user details.

Comment: OK. I have updated my answer. Missed it with original test data.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: Simply I am using `CURSOR` with `MIN MAX` date of each `AccountId` and `JOIN` to generate dates in the range and most importantly `TOP 1` to fetch previous values detail

```
DECLARE @MinDt DATE, @MaxDt DATE, @AccountId VARCHAR(200)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#dates') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #dates

CREATE TABLE #dates(AccountId VARCHAR(200),dates DATE)

DECLARE b_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT AccountId FROM #temp    
OPEN b_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM b_cursor INTO @AccountId
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN
    SELECT 
        @MinDt = MIN(CAST(CONCAT(Yr,'-',Month,'-',01) AS DATE)),
        @MaxDt = MAX(CAST(CONCAT(Yr,'-',Month,'-',01) AS DATE))
    FROM #Temp WHERE AccountId = @AccountId

    ;WITH account_detail(AccountId, account_dates, cnt)AS
    (
        SELECT @AccountId, @MinDt, 0 AS cnt
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT AccountId,DATEADD(MONTH, (cnt+1), @MinDt), cnt + 1 
        FROM account_detail r 
        WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, (cnt+1), @MinDt) <= @MaxDt
    )
    INSERT INTO #dates(AccountId, dates) 
    SELECT AccountId, account_dates FROM account_detail
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)

    FETCH NEXT FROM b_cursor INTO @AccountId
END
CLOSE b_cursor
DEALLOCATE  b_cursor

SELECT 
    ISNULL(te.AccountId,t.AccountId) AS AccountId, 
    ISNULL(te.Churn, t.Churn) AS Churn, 
    MONTH(ur.dates) [Month],  
    YEAR(ur.dates) Yr
FROM #dates ur
LEFT JOIN #temp te ON te.Month = MONTH(ur.dates) AND te.Yr = YEAR(ur.dates) 
AND te.AccountId = ur.AccountId
OUTER APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * 
            FROM #temp 
            WHERE CAST(CONCAT(Yr,'-',Month,'-',01) AS DATE) <= ur.dates 
                AND AccountId = ur.AccountId
            ORDER BY CAST(CONCAT(Yr,'-',Month,'-',01) AS DATE) DESC) t
ORDER BY ur.AccountId ASC
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
    AccountId       Churn       Month   Yr
Tst05716825     Active      9       2016
Tst05716825     Active      10      2016
Tst05716825     Active      11      2016
Tst05716825     Active      12      2016
Tst05716825     Active      1       2017
Tst05716825     Active      2       2017
Tst05716825     Suspend     3       2017
Tst05716825     Suspend     4       2017
Tst05716825     Suspend     5       2017
Tst05716825     Suspend     6       2017
Tst05716825     Suspend     7       2017
Tst05716825     Suspend     8       2017
Tst05716825     Suspend     9       2017
Tst05716825     Terminate   10      2017
TstNew09567     Active      11      2017
TstNew09567     Active      12      2017
TstNew09567     Active      1       2018
TstNew09567     Suspend     2       2018
TstNew09567     Suspend     3       2018
TstNew09567     Suspend     4       2018
TstNew09567     Suspend     5       2018
TstNew09567     Terminate   6       2018
TstNw09567      Active      3       2016
TstNw09567      Active      4       2016
TstNw09567      Active      5       2016
TstNw09567      Active      6       2016
TstNw09567      Active      7       2016
TstNw09567      Active      8       2016
TstNw09567      Active      9       2016
TstNw09567      Active      10      2016
TstNw09567      Active      11      2016
TstNw09567      Active      12      2016
TstNw09567      Active      1       2017
TstNw09567      Active      2       2017
TstNw09567      Active      3       2017
TstNw09567      Active      4       2017
TstNw09567      Active      5       2017
TstNw09567      Active      6       2017
TstNw09567      Active      7       2017
TstNw09567      Active      8       2017
TstNw09567      Active      9       2017
TstNw09567      Active      10      2017
TstNw09567      Active      11      2017
TstNw09567      Active      12      2017
TstNw09567      Active      1       2018
TstNw09567      Active      2       2018
TstNw09567      Terminate   3       2018
```

Comment: Thanks but I want previous value for missing month. In your example getting churn value as ACTIVE. instead of ACTIVE want previous value.

Comment: Sorry brother, comparison date was hard coded before for testing purpose and forgot to change with column name while posting. Please check it now.

Comment: It is getting fail if month and year overlapping with other account. If we add this 2 row new row with new accountid ('TstNw09567', 'Active', 3, 2016), ('TstNw09567', 'Terminate', 3, 2018) above logic fill fail. :(

Comment: Can you please mention where and how it's failed ? I have verified it with your changed data it's working absolutely fine. am I missing anything ?

Comment: I should get TstNw09567 this user data as ACTIVE from Mar 2016 till Feb 2018 means total 24 rows as ACTIVE and one row as Terminate. for same account.But I am getting only 7 rows for TstNw09567. After that it is discarding bcoz another account id Tst05716825 start from 9-2016.